# How would you test which mobile menu pattern works better?

Tags: user-research, usability-testing, ux-designer

I have three mobile menu patterns I want to find out which one is easier/faster to use, ie, 1) top nav that pushes main content down, 2) top nav that takes over the whole screen, 3) side menu drawer. For both of the top nav patterns, they work as accordions to show the sub nav; For the side menu drawer, there is a second sub nav page in the menu, users can hit "back" to go back to the top nav list.

My test method is a between group test, each group of users(5) will use one type of top menu pattern (prototypes with the same content) to finish a few tasks that involves using the menu.For instance, find FAQ page(*the FAQ lives in the top nav*), find contact page (*lives in sub nav*). The data I want to collect is time on task and user satisfaction.

I have two questions, 1) How would you improve the test or would you approach it totally different? 2) This test doesn't reflect the amount of nav items may also influence user performance, eg, maybe nav with a lot of items is better for the top nav pattern that takes over the page. How can this be incorporated in the test or should it be another test?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried the 1st category will open side menu drawer, and sub-category will be top horizontal?

Comment: That's interesting @SourabhRangdal, do you mean like apple.com? It would be harder for the sites I work on, since they often have longer labels.

Comment: Apple.com has a 2 slice icon,  which is a drop down and yes you can see the sub-category to next screen. Did you tried taxonomies or alternative for the long label. Am I allow to see the data?

Comment: I think you are in a good shape. For your first question, you may want to also collect users' success rate in your research. Furthermore, how will you test the UX of the side menu drawer? You only mentioned the top menu pattern in the test... For your second question, the number of nav items should be the same in both situations in your test, which should also be roughly the same as your desired amount for the final product, to minimize the inaccuracy of your research :)

Comment: Thanks @WenG! I definitely should collect users' success rates. To test the side menu drawer, I'd ask the users to finish the same tasks that involve locating content using different levels of navigation. Do you have other suggestions to test it?

Answer (score 1):

### Complement your task analysis with statistical measurement

I think you've taken the right approach of doing a task analysis. To answer your questions, you can complement the success rate with statistically measuring the test using [Adjusted Wald interval method](http://measuringu.com/wald/). (The link provides a handy calculator along with a brief explanation of the method)

To quote from the book - [Quantifying the user experience](http://measuringu.com/book/quantifying-the-user-experiencepractical-statistics-for-user-research/):

> "Understanding the actual percent of users affected by the problem can
> guide the prioritization of problems and reduce some of the skepticism
> that comes with small sample sizes"

You can repeat the task analysis with adjusted Waldo test for other variations like increasing or decreasing the nav items.You'll have statistical anaylsis to back you decisions and convince the stakeholders more confidently.

For user satisfaction, you can carry out a [net promoter score](https://www.netpromoter.com/know/) test and again measure it statistically.

Hope this helps!